# Could not instantiate mail function: A PHPMailer Error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a contact form. And I searched all over the internet how to send email, and they always say that it is better to use PHPMailer than mail() function.

The contact form consists of: Name, Email, Comments, and a Send Button.

I just followed this tutorial: https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/ but it's not working as I always got the error called: 'Could not instantiate mail function.' when I already installed the Composer.

Proof that I've already installed the composer:
[Composer installed with autoload.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsyG2.png)

Here's my code inside the php tags:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'C:\xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $em = $_POST['email'];
    $nm = $_POST['name'];
    $msg = $_POST['comments'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom($em, $nm);
    $mail->addAddress('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Admin');
    $mail->Subject = 'Concern';
    $mail->isHTML(TRUE);
    $mail->Body = '$em';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Thank you for answering this question! It'll be a big help!

**UPDATE:**
Content/File of the composer.json:

{
     "require": {
          "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide linked from nearly everywhere (including in your error message), you'll find it contains [a detailed explanation for this error](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#could-not-instantiate-mail-function) and how to solve it. Copying from there:

This means that your PHP installation is not configured to call the `mail()` function correctly (e.g. `sendmail_path` is not set correctly in your `php.ini`), or you have no local mail server installed and configured. To fix this you need to do one or more of these things:

- Install a local mail server (e.g. postfix).
- Ensure that your `sendmail_path` points at the sendmail binary (usually `/usr/sbin/sendmail`) in your `php.ini`. Note that on Ubuntu/Debian you may have multiple `.ini` files in `/etc/php5/mods-available` and possibly other locations.
- Use `isSendmail()` and set the path to the sendmail binary in PHPMailer (`$mail->Sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';`).
- Use `isSMTP()` and send directly using SMTP.

This is nothing to do with how you load composer's autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting services return this error when the email is considered a spam. Try using an email address with the same domain as your website.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of: `require 'C:\xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';`

Try: `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

This is assuming that /vendor is a sub  directory of your document root.

Comment: I tried doing it, but it gave me error: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\GGA/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory and require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\GGA/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: What's the error? Also, please post the contents of your composer.json file.

Comment: composer.json - {
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
    }
}

Comment: I think the issue here is that maybe you didn't issue the command:
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
From the command line, which needs to be done (usually) from the root of your web directory.

Comment: I did though. I used the cmd to execute the composer require phpmailer/phpmailer. Image: https://i.imgur.com/9xG8esD.png. Should I just restart installing the composer all over again? But I don't know how to uninstall it...

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried to use composer on Windows. I've always used it on a Linux server.

Comment: How you load composer has no bearing on this error.